# How to create warning messages in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation

I would like to add style to the validation messages based on enum type.
*FluentValidation* offers possibility to add custom state for messages by using `WithState` method. Depending on which enum is used it would add a class for that message in HTML, so later I could add styling to it.

*Model validator class:*

```
public class SampleModelValidator : AbstractValidator<SampleModelValidator>
{
    public SampleModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Age)).NotEmpty()
                // Using custom state here
                .WithState(o => MsgTypeEnum.WARNING)
                .WithMessage("Warning: This field is optional, but better fill it!");
    }
}
```

*Controller action method:*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SampleModel model)
{
    ValidationResult results = this.validator.Validate(model);
    int warningCount = results.Errors
                .Where(o => o.CustomState?.ToString() == MsgTypeEnum.WARNING.ToString())
                .Count();
    ...
}
```

I noticed that ASP.NET MVC is using `unobtrusive.js` by default and adding class `.field-validation-error` to each error message. So I guess needs to override that logic somehow.  
**How can I add styles to validation messages depending on provided enum type?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to implement this. First need to create a html helper that will build the html tags and add necessary classes to them. This helper allows to display multiple messages with different types for one field/property. 
Great article that explains how to do it, possibly the only one out there! 
[http://www.pearson-and-steel.co.uk/](http://www.pearson-and-steel.co.uk/how-to-use-fluentvalidation-to-display-validation-errors-and-warnings/)

***Html Helper method***

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFluent<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, int? itemIndex = null)
{
    List<ValidationFailure> validationFailures = html.ViewData["ValidationFailures"] as List<ValidationFailure>;
    string exprMemberName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    var priorityFailures = validationFailures.Where(f => f.PropertyName.EndsWith(exprMemberName));

    if (priorityFailures.Count() == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Property name in 'validationFailures' may also be stored like this 'SomeRecords[0].PropertyName'
    string propertyName = itemIndex.HasValue ? $"[{itemIndex}].{exprMemberName}" : exprMemberName;

    // There can be multiple messages for one property
    List<TagBuilder> tags = new List<TagBuilder>();
    foreach (var validationFailure in priorityFailures.ToList())
    {
        if (validationFailure.PropertyName.EndsWith(propertyName))
        {
            TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
            string customState = validationFailure.CustomState?.ToString();

            // Handling the message type and adding class attribute
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customState))
            {
                span.AddCssClass(string.Format("field-validation-error"));
            }
            else if (customState == MsgTypeEnum.WARNING.ToString())
            {
                span.AddCssClass(string.Format("field-validation-warning"));
            }

            // Adds message itself to the html element
            span.SetInnerText(validationFailure.ErrorMessage);
            tags.Add(span);
        }
    }

    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    // Join all html tags togeather
    foreach(var t in tags)
    {
        strB.Append(t.ToString());
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(strB.ToString());
}
```

Also, inside controller action method need to get validator errors and store them inside a session.

***Controller action method***

```
// In controller you also need to set the ViewData. I don't really like to use itself
// but did not found other solution
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SampleModel model)
{
   IList<ValidationFailure> errors = this.validator.Validate(model).Errors;
   ViewData["ValidationFailures"] = errors as List<ValidationFailure>;

    ...
}
```

And simply use that html helper inside view.

***View***

```
// In html view (using razor syntax)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SomeRecords.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFluent(o => Model.SomeRecords[i].PropertyName, i)

    ...
}
```

The last index parameter is required only if looping through lists.