# FluentValidation: Update the validated model for some optional properties inside the validator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I was wondering if there is possible to update the validated model inside the FluentValidations validator for some optional parameters, in case that these parameters are invalid?

Here is some code:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.FirstName).NotNull().Length(5, 100);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.LastName).NotNull().Length(5, 100);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.MiddleName).Length(5, 100).When(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.MiddleName));
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
        Customer customer = new Customer { FirstName = "first name", LastName = "last name" };
        CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();

        var result = validator.Validate(customer);

        Console.WriteLine(result.IsValid);
```

So in my case, I want to set the middle name to null when it's not valid and save a warning in a variable but still treat the model as valid.

Comment: It is not a good idea to update the object passed to validation the Validator should only validate the input entity, and return the validation result and that is it.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it:

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.FirstName).NotNull().Length(5, 100);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.LastName).NotNull().Length(5, 100).OnAnyFailure((customer) => 
        {
            customer.LastName = null;
            customer.Warnings.Add(nameof(customer.LastName));
        });
        RuleFor(customer => customer.MiddleName).Length(5, 100).When(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.MiddleName));
    }
}
```

Comment: OnAnyFailure is now obsolete in latest version but we can achieve by using Custom rule to update model

RuleFor(x => x).Custom((customer, context) => {
if(customer.Address?.length>150)
  customer.Address = customer.Address.Substring(0, 150);
});

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to update the object passed to validation the Validator should only validate the input entity, and return the validation result and that is it. I would suggest you to have two validators. One for business critical rules and one for warnings so if the first validator returns that model is invalid you return the result, if no critical errors then you validate the warnings and then you can decide to proceed or not and manipulate with your model! 
For example

```
    public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCriticalValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.FirstName).NotNull().Length(5, 100);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.LastName).NotNull().Length(5, 100);
    }
}

public class CustomerWarningValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(customer => customer.MiddleName).Length(5, 100).When(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.MiddleName));
    }
}
```

and then in the code

```
            Customer customer = new Customer();

        CustomerCriticalValidator criticalValidator = new CustomerCriticalValidator();

        CustomerWarningValidator warningValidator = new CustomerWarningValidator();

        var validationResult = criticalValidator.Validate(customer);
        if (validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            var result = warningValidator.Validate(customer);
            if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                //DO what you need with customer    
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually manipulating the passed-in value is more than just validation.  So FluentValidator might not be the best place for it.  How about putting that particular logic in the setter?:

```
string middleName;
public string MiddleName { 
    get => middleName; 
    set { 
        middleName = 
            value.Length < 5 || value.Length > 100 
            ? null 
            : value; 
    }
```

---

**Edit: Responding to concerns raised in comments**

So, regarding your desire to show a warning message.  I assume you already know how to do this within FluentValidation.  It seems like a not-so-fun topic, at least when I looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322368/how-to-create-warning-messages-in-fluentvalidation) resource.  So I'll leave the actual warning logic out of this response.

But, in order to give you a fighting chance at even raising such a warning, you need it stored somewhere.  So just add a field for this and handle it in your setter logic:

```
public string middleNameWarning;

string middleName;
public string MiddleName { 

    get => middleName; 

    set { 

        if (value.Length < 5 || value.Length > 100) {
            middleName = null;
            middleNameWarning = 
                $"'{value}' is not a valid MiddleName.  It was reset to null. "
                + "Set MiddleName explicitly to a valid value to remove this warning.";
        }
        else {
            middleName = value;
            middleNameWarning = null;
        }

    }

}
```

`middleNameWarning` has to be public in order for you to access it (I was able to confirm this) with FluentValidation.  If you don't like that maybe you can have a method access it.  Also, it can possibly just be a boolean and you can set the text elsewhere when you discover its value is true.

Finally, just to confirm that what your original approach might not work out as you hope, I discovered a closed [issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/751) on the GitHub repository for someone asking how to do something similar.  Here was the response from JeremySkinner:

> Hi, FluentValidation only performs validation on a pre-populated object, it doesn't modify/change the values of properties. You could technically do this with a custom validator that does the work, but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: The thing is that when I'm validating, I want to add and some warnings in the response saying that some values were ignored due to invalid value.

Comment: And also, if the model has different consumers, each consumer may have different rules.

Comment: I'm thinking of a potential solution to your first concern.  Does FluentValidator allow rules against private fields/properties?

Comment: I don't think so because the validator it's a separate class and you can't access the privat fields/properties.

Comment: @BudaGavril Look at my answer I think it will helps to you

Comment: @BudaGavril and if you will have performance issues with FluentValidator here is a nuget package with FastValidator that is doing the same job but 100 times faster https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastValidator/